# Clone specific folder from git hub repository

Tags: github, git-clone

I want to clone the specific directory.From this `https://github.com/FilledStacks/flutter-tutorials.git` repository in which `https://github.com/FilledStacks/flutter-tutorials/tree/master/001-tik_tok_ui/phase1` folder to my computer. Only specific `phase1` required. I am beginner on git hub.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think this is possible in GIT. You can download the directory from a repo.

Comment: This is possible as explained in


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/how-do-i-clone-a-subdirectory-only-of-a-git-repository/13738951#13738951